# How to get data from UIDatePicker - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the data from the UIDatePicker, for example the user picked a date as 7:15 PM
  How do I get the data from that so I can manipulate and use it for some other function?

If you have any questions or need any clarifications please comment them down below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a handler for your UIDatePicker like so:

```
yourDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DatePickerViewController.handler(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

And then do something like this in your handler:

```
@objc func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    var strDate = timeFormatter.string(from: yourDatePicker.date)
    // do what you want to do with the string.
}
```

Comment: There is an error on the first line saying `Expected declaration`

Comment: Where is the first line placed? Is it in somewhere like viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, everything is placed inside the class' curly braces. Should it be in viewDidLoad()

Comment: It needs to be placed somewhere after the datepicker has been instantiated.  Are you using storyboards/IB? Or is the datepicker created in code?  In the former case, make an outlet for the datepicker and then use it in viewdidload.

Comment: It should be timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)